# Using Ecto select, select_merge, and joins

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to figure out how to combine a select, and a join table, but running into issues.

Let's say I have table A, table B, and table C. Table A has some values, and Table B has many items in Table C.

My query is something like this:

```
query = from(
  a in TableA,
  select: %NewStruct{
    a: a.value  
  }
) 

from(
  a in query,
  join: b in TableB,
  on: b.a_id == a.id,
  join: c in TableC,
  on: c.b_id == b.id,
  select_merge: %{
    c: [c]
  }
)
|> Repo.all()
```

This works in the sense that it will return 3 structs. They all have the same value of `a`, but `c` is each item from TableC.

Current result:

```
[
  %NewStruct{
    a: "value"
    id: 1,
    c: %TableC{
      id: 1
    }
  },
  %NewStruct{
    a: "value"
    id: 1,
    c: %TableC{
      id: 2
    }
  },
  %NewStruct{
    a: "value"
    id: 1,
    c: %TableC{
      id: 3
    }
  }
]
```

Normally, I know to use `preload: [c: c]` to get ecto to combine all of the joined items, and nest within `a.c`. But I can't in this situation, since `NewStruct` is just a `defstruct`. I tried turning `NewStruct` into an `embedded_schema`, but I was unable to get the `has_many` definitions to pickup properly.

My question is this: is there anyway to tell Ecto that the join table `c` should be preloaded/nested within `a.c`? I understand that if you did something like `SELECT * FROM a INNER JOIN c.b_id ON b.id` that you'd get a result of 3 rows from PSQL. But I do know that sometimes Ecto can work some magic, and wondering if I'm missing something.

Desired result:

```
[
  %NewStruct{
    a: "value"
    id: 1,
    c: [
      %TableC{
        id: 1
      },
      %TableC{
        id: 2
      },
      %TableC{
        id: 3
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would build the query, preload `TableC` and only then `select` into the struct.

```
TableA
|> join(:left, [a], b in assoc(a, :table_b))
|> join(:left, [b], c in assoc(b, :table_c))
|> preload([b, c], [:table_b, table_c: c])
|> select([a], %NewStruct{a: a.value, c: [c]})
|> Repo.all()
```

Untested, but it should work.